# How to generate random text in each iteration in Jmeter tool

Tags: r, random, jmeter

[added the loop count as 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwHPB.png)
Used randomString function to generate random string at each iteration

After 10 loops random string - example: "testabc" only generated 10 times.

What need to change if I expect 10 random Text

I have changed loop count, number of threads & so on.
But the same result as random string generated as - "Testabc" for 10 loop counts

Comment: Where is your random String? in User defined Variables? or in request?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) and [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function configured like

```
${__RandomString(7,abcdefjhijklmnopqrtsuvwxyz,)}
```

[image]

So most probably your test configuration is not correct, if you're using the function inside [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)  - it will be initialized **once** when the test starts. Just use the above expression (amend it accordingly to match your requirements) directly in the place where the random string should be created and that would be it.